# How to add a specific event handler to a unspecified control?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking to try and create something like the following:

If the user leaves the last textbox (for example let's say TextBox8), then a new textbox is created below textbox8 with the name textbox9. I have this part, but how would I make it so that if textbox9 is left, the same events happen, so on and so forth?

```
Private Sub TextBox8_LoseFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox8.LostFocus
' Textbox 9 creation code which then creates the next textbox etc.
End Sub
```

If anybody can offer a better way of doing this sort of thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AddHandler to add a eventhandler to a control you create at run time

```
    AddHandler TextBox9.LostFocus, AddressOf TextBox8_LoseFocus
```